# Count points inside triangle fast

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I need to find the number of points in a given list that are inside a triangle. The problem here is, there can be up to a million points.

I tried a simple approach: if the area of the triangle is equal to the sum of the areas of 3 triangles formed by taking 2 of the triangle's points at a time and the point to check, its inside. This doesn't have any precision errors, since I don't divide by two to find the area.

But I need something faster. The goal is speed. Can it be made faster by some sort of preprocessing, ignoring some points based on some criteria or something similar?

**EDIT**:
Forgot to add a critical detail. The points once given, are fixed. Then the points are static, and need to be checked for up to a million triangles...

**EDIT 2**: Turns out that a good(maybe optimal too) way to do it was using a line sweep. Still, thanks for your answers!

Comment: The obvious approach that springs to mind is to compute a bounding box and screen first based on its coordinates.

Comment: If you post your counting function, there may be other optimization tricks people can provide beyond algorithmic.

Comment: What are your time constraints? Milliseconds? Seconds? If it's seconds just do a linear search using the answer Alexey Frunze suggested. If it's milliseconds or sub milliseconds then consider using some space partitioning tree, e.g., a quad tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the computational geometry weenies the fastest way to do this is by a barycentric coordinates transformation. In a case where you have a fixed triangle and many test points, then this approach will be especially fast, because once you have computed the barycentric coordinates of the 3 points of the triangle you have done most of the work. Here is the full algorithm where ABC are the triangle and P is the point under test:

```
// Compute vectors        
v0 = C - A
v1 = B - A
v2 = P - A

// Compute dot products
dot00 = dot(v0, v0)
dot01 = dot(v0, v1)
dot02 = dot(v0, v2)
dot11 = dot(v1, v1)
dot12 = dot(v1, v2)

// Compute barycentric coordinates
invDenom = 1 / (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01)
u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * invDenom
v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * invDenom

// Check if point is in triangle
return (u >= 0) && (v >= 0) && (u + v < 1)
```

Here the barycentric coordinates are computed with respect to A, but B or C would have worked as well.

To test additional points you only need to recompute v2, dot02, dot12, u and v. Quantities such as invDenom stay the same.

Comment: This is probably the fastest if you profile. No branching, coherent memory access and just a few add/multiplies.

Comment: Yes, this algorithm is the result of thousands of weenies lying in bed at night for hours staring at the ceiling wondering how they can make their collision detection algorithms faster.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  One suggestion: You might want to amend your last statement to clarify that quantities such as invDenom stay the same, so long as the triangle vertices don't move.

Answer (score 8):

A point is inside a triangle if it's to the left (right) of every side. You can calculate the cross products (just one component of it, actually) of a vector constructed of a point to be tested and one of the triangle vertices and the 3 vectors lying on the sides of the triangle (all in clock-wise or all in counter-clock-wise direction). See if the computed component of all 3 has the same sign (all 3 negative or all 3 positive). That'll tell you the point is in. Fast, no problems with precision, at least, if you use integers for the task.

You may stop further calculations for every point once you see it's to the wrong side of one of the triangle sides.

Sample code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 22
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  78

// Simulated frame buffer
char Screen[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];

void SetPixel(int x, int y, char color)
{
  if ((x < 0) || (x >= SCREEN_WIDTH) ||
      (y < 0) || (y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    return;

  Screen[y][x] = color;
}

void Visualize(void)
{
  int x, y;

  for (y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++)
  {
    for (x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++)
      printf("%c", Screen[y][x]);

    printf("\n");
  }
}

typedef struct
{
  int x, y;
} Point2D;

int main(void)
{
  // triangle vertices
  Point2D vx0 = { SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 7 };
  Point2D vx1 = { SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 7, SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2 / 3 };
  Point2D vx2 = { SCREEN_WIDTH / 7, SCREEN_HEIGHT * 6 / 7 };
  // vectors lying on triangle sides
  Point2D v0, v1, v2;
  // current point coordinates
  int x, y;

  // calculate side vectors

  v0.x = vx1.x - vx0.x;
  v0.y = vx1.y - vx0.y;

  v1.x = vx2.x - vx1.x;
  v1.y = vx2.y - vx1.y;

  v2.x = vx0.x - vx2.x;
  v2.y = vx0.y - vx2.y;

  // process all points

  for (y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++)
    {
      int z1 = (x - vx0.x) * v0.y - (y - vx0.y) * v0.x;
      int z2 = (x - vx1.x) * v1.y - (y - vx1.y) * v1.x;
      int z3 = (x - vx2.x) * v2.y - (y - vx2.y) * v2.x;

      if ((z1 * z2 > 0) && (z1 * z3 > 0))
        SetPixel(x, y, '+'); // point is to the right (left) of all vectors
      else
        SetPixel(x, y, '-');
    }

  // draw triangle vertices

  SetPixel(vx0.x, vx0.y, '0');
  SetPixel(vx1.x, vx1.y, '1');
  SetPixel(vx2.x, vx2.y, '2');

  // visualize the result

  Visualize();

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/XEwEHN)):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------0--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------++++------------------------------------
------------------------------------++++++++----------------------------------
----------------------------------+++++++++++++-------------------------------
--------------------------------+++++++++++++++++-----------------------------
------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------
----------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++------------------------
--------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------
-------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------
-----------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------
---------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------
-------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++1-----------
-----------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------
---------------++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------------------
-------------++++++++++++-----------------------------------------------------
-----------2------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I can't believe this got 8 votes. Computing cross products is much more computationally intensive than a dot product. If this poster actually provided working code, this would be obvious.

Comment: @TylerDurden dx1*dy2-dy1*dx2 is much more computationally intensive than dx1*dx2+dy1*dy2? And you only need 1 to 3 of these dx1*dy2-dy1*dx2 per point.

Comment: CGI programmers have been computing points interior to triangles for 25 years, and the way they do it is the way I said. They definitely do not compute cross products to do this calculation and if you write a working program to do this computation this will be obvious to you why dot products of barycentric coordinates are used.

Comment: @TylerDurden So, how bad is the sample code that I've just added?

Comment: I don't see how the code above in any way relates to the problem. The inputs to the problem are a list of n P(x0,y0) points and a million or more triangles, each consisting of 3 points A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2) and C(x3,y3). The result is to determine if any of the n points is in any of the millions of triangles and return true, otherwise false.

Comment: @TylerDurden - Please don't accuse others of vote fraud without proof. I can tell you that there is nothing of the sort here, and I have some very sophisticated tools for sussing this out. Focus on constructive criticism of the technical content here instead.

Answer (score 4):

Simple pre-filter is to eliminate any points whose coordinates obviously lie outside of the bounds of the triangle's corners. e.g.

```
  a
+
|\
| \ b
|c \
+---+  d
```

A and D are obviously outside. A's Y coord is far above the triangle's maximum Y, and D is obviously beyond the triangle's maximum X.

That leaves B and C for testing.

Comment: I'd like to add that if the points are already sorted either by x or y, then it's worth doing a binary search to try to narrow down the range of points to those within the min/max of the x (if x-sorted) or the y (if y-sorted), of the triangles.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to accelerate the computation.

Compute a quadtree for the triangle (stopping at arbitrary resolution) and for each node (square), store a flag saying whether the node is completely inside, completely outside, or partially inside the triangle. A node that's partially inside the triangle can potentially have children (depending on depth)

For each point, traverse the quadtree. If we visit a node that's completely outside or inside the triangle, we're all set. If we're unsure about if we're in the triangle (node is partially inside the triangle) and the current node has children, we test against its children recursively. If we hit a leaf node that's partially inside the triangle, do an analytical point - triangle containment check.

Comment: @Bruce: I'd still use a tree structure.  You can trivially accept all points from quads that are interior to the triangles, and only have to do line tests on points in quads on the triangle sides.  As Alexey pointed out, side tests are easier if you orient them properly, or you can do a barycenter test that Tyler suggests.  The key is that with the tree that splits based on the number of points in a bucket, the number of interior points that you can't trivially dectect is small.

Answer (score 1):

First of all sort your points given in the list by y coordinates and in tie of y coordinates x coordinates. Now start from below of you lowest y coordinate (think of a parallel line to x axis ) and move it up 1 unit you also have the equation of the line segments formed by the end points of your triangle . Now eliminate some obvious points as suggested by Marc B. And for the rest of points having the same y coordinate as your imaginary parallel line to x axis moving upwards by a unit step each time put check whether they are inside or outside the triangle by putting in the equations of line joining end points of the triangle. You can easily such points having same y coordinates by doing binary search on your list of coordinates which you had sorted earlier according to y coordinates. This way your algo takes O(Yrangeoftriangle*nlogn) for each query. ALSO The question is pretty well asked on codechef long .